# _tkinter.TclError: image "Horseshoe.gif" doesn't exist

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I am making a slot machine in Python using Tkinter.
The code file and images are all contained in one folder:

[image]

However when I run the code, and the images are called, I get the error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: image "imagename.gif" doesn't exist
```

Here is my entire code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

photoList = ["7.gif","Apple.gif","Bell.gif","Clover.gif","Diamond.gif","Grape.gif","Horseshoe.gif","Pear.gif","Strawberry.gif"]

slotMachine = Tk()

file = open("credit.txt", mode = "w")
file.write("50")
file.close()

def getMoney():
    file = open("credit.txt", mode = "r")
    lst = file.readlines()
    money = int(lst[0].strip("\n"))
    file.close()
    file = open("credit.txt", mode = "w")
    file.write(str(money-5))
    file.close()
    return money

def addMoney(add):
    money = getMoney() + add
    file = open("credit.txt", mode = "w")
    file.write(str(money))
    file.close()
    lbl5.config(text = "Money: £{0}".format(money))

def spin():
    credit = getMoney()
    if credit > 0:
        credit = credit - 5
        lbl5.config(text = "Money: £{0}".format(credit))
        slot1 = photoList[randint(0,8)]
        slot2 = photoList[randint(0,8)]
        slot3 = photoList[randint(0,8)]
        canvas1.create_image(26,26, image = slot1)
        canvas2.create_image(26,26, image = slot2)
        canvas3.create_image(26,26, image = slot3)
    else:
        lbl5.config(text = "Out Of Credit!")

    if slot1 == slot2 or slot2 == slot3 or slot1 == slot3:
        lbl6.config(text = "Double Match! Winnings: £5")
        addMoney(5)
    elif slot1 == slot2 and slot2 == slot3:
        lbl6.config(text = "Full House! Winnings: £20")
        addMoney(20)
    else:
        lbl6.config(text = "No Win! Try Again!")

lbl1 = Label(slotMachine, text = "Welcome to the Slot Machine!", font = ("Calibri", 16))
lbl1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
lbl1.pack()

canvas1 = Canvas(slotMachine, height = 52, width = 52)
##canvas1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

canvas2 = Canvas(slotMachine, height = 52, width = 52)
##canvas2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

canvas3 = Canvas(slotMachine, height = 52, width = 52)
##canvas3.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

photo1 = PhotoImage(file = "x.gif")

canvas1.create_image(26,26, image = photo1)
canvas2.create_image(26,26, image = photo1)
canvas3.create_image(26,26, image = photo1)

lbl5 = Label(slotMachine, text = "Money: £50")
lbl5.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
lbl5.pack()

spinBtn = Button(slotMachine, text = "Spin - £5", command = spin)
spinBtn.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
spinBtn.pack()

lbl6 = Label(slotMachine, text = "", font = ("Calibri", 16))
lbl6.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
lbl6.pack()

slotMachine.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
photoList = ["7.gif","Apple.gif","Bell.gif",...]
...
slot1 = photoList[randint(0,8)]
...
canvas1.create_image(26,26, image = slot1)
```

`photoList` is a list of file names. When you create the image you are giving it a file name. That is not how you create images on a canvas.  You have to create a `PhotoImage` instance using the filename, and then pass that instance to the `create_image` method.

Since you are using these images more than once, it would make sense to convert all of the filenames to images first, and store the images in `photoList` rather than store the paths to the images. With that, you wouldn't have to change the code that creates the images.

Note: besides this problem, you've also got the program that you keep creating images on the canvas in the same place, stacking them on top of each other. Although it will take a while, eventually you'll run out of memory. You should either destroy the old images, or reuse them.